# Tap on notification restart application and NotificationTapped event not firing

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am using [Plugin.LocalNotification](https://github.com/thudugala/Plugin.LocalNotification)
 to receive notification. I want to use `NotificationCenter.Current.NotificationTapped` event but on Android device event is not triggered. On iOS device, it work's

I created 2 views :

- MainView
- NotifView

I send notif from NotifView page, I left app (by clicking on home button). 5 seconds later I got notification, I click on it, app restart with splashscreen. Event and treaments are not executed.

**MainView.xaml.cs**

```
public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        NotificationCenter.Current.NotificationTapped += Current_NotificationTapped;

        var vm = new MainViewModel(this);
        BindingContext = vm;
        _ = vm.Initialize();
    }

    private void Current_NotificationTapped(NotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        Tour tour = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tour>(e.Request.ReturningData);

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            DisplayAlert("", "it work's", "ok");
            //(App.Current as App).Main.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Settings());
        });
    }
```

**NotifView.xaml.cs**

```
public MainView(Tour tourData)
    {
        await NotificationRequestHelper.RequestOrder(tourData);
    }
```

**NotificationRequestHelper.cs**

```
async public static Task RequestOrder(Tour tour)
    {
        var notification = new NotificationRequest
        {
            NotificationId = 100,
            Title = "Notif here",
            ReturningData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tour, Formatting.None,
                new JsonSerializerSettings()
                {
                    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
                }),
            Schedule =
            {
                NotifyTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5) // Used for Scheduling local notification, if not specified notification will show immediately.
            }
        };

        await NotificationCenter.Current.Show(notification);
    }
```

**MainActivity.cs**

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        CachedImageRenderer.Init(enableFastRenderer: true);
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        NotificationCenter.CreateNotificationChannel();

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

        Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(this);
        Plugin.InputKit.Platforms.Droid.Config.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        CarouselViewRenderer.Init();
        CachedImageRenderer.InitImageViewHandler();
        StatusBar.Activity = this;

        // set fullscreen
        this.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
        Instance = this;

        LoadApplication(new App());

        Intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);

        NotificationCenter.NotifyNotificationTapped(Intent);
    }

    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        NotificationCenter.NotifyNotificationTapped(intent);
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);
    }
```

**What I tried to do**
I found topics which told :

- Add `NotificationCenter.CreateNotificationChannel();` and `NotificationCenter.NotifyNotificationTapped(Intent);` into MainActivity.cs constructor
- Override `OnNewIntent` adding `NotificationCenter.NotifyNotificationTapped(intent);` into MainActivity.cs
- Add `LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop` at the top of MainActivity.cs
- Add `Intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);` into MainActivity.cs constructor

Did someone has this issue, and how to fix it ?

Comment: I tried to test your code but failed because it's not complete. So I used the [demo](https://github.com/thudugala/Plugin.LocalNotification/tree/master/Sample/Direct) on the github and it works correctly. In addition, I also used your tapped event at first and everything was ok. So you can refer to the demo at first and add a breakpoint at the tapped event. Furthermore,why and how you call the construction method of mainview in NotifView.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I already tried demo, it work's but I don't see what I missing. I decided to follow this implementation that work's well : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/local-notifications

Comment: You can try to add a breakpoint to your tapped event at first. In addition, you should avoid creating the construction method of one class in other classes.